# Ruby on rails, Get values from database in descending order

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a database that stores scores, and usernames.

I want to make this databases entries appear on a view page in descending order by score.

In the controller I am trying

```
Highscore.order("score DESC").find([value])
```

However this gives me the value by date and not by descending score, meaning .order isn't doing anything. I want to be able to retrieve individual entries like this but sorted by score.

if I do

```
Highscore.order("score DESC").find((1..(Highscore.count)).to_a)
```

it gives me the the correct order but I can't organize the text how I want to
and it appears on the same line separated by comma's.

Comment: Highscore.order(score: :desc).first(value).last(1)                                           Works.  Thanks, Nicolas for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, it will return the last 10 scores 
`@last_10 = Highscore.order(count: :desc).first(10)`

Use it in a HTML.ERB file

```
<ul>
  <%for record in @last_10%>
    <li>record.username</li>
  <%end%>
</ul>
```

Comment: This gives me an error. PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "highscores.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT "highscores".* FROM "highscores" ORDER BY "highscore... ^ : SELECT "highscores".* FROM "highscores" ORDER BY "highscores"."count" DESC LIMIT $1

Comment: That will retrieve the Active Records, which you can use as an array to make it display as you want, for example in a html.erb file

Comment: I found a way to make it work.  Highscore.order(score: :desc).first(value).last(1) Thanks

Comment: Why do you use a `for` loop to iterate over the element?

Comment: It was just in case you wanted more than one element and display them together, that's why I'm using 10 elements that would be added to a list